# Why do some transitive verbs take に instead of を?

Tags: grammar, transitivity

> ヘスティアはせっせと残りの「神聖文字」を付け足し、己のしてやれる**ことに努める。**

I don't really understand why に used instead を even though 努める is transitive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mixing up two different つとめる with different kanji. 努める is always intransitive.

- [**務【つと】める**](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/147797/m0u/) (*transitive*; ～を務める): be in charge, play a role. [Examples](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8B%99%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B).
- [**努【つと】める**](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/147796/m0u/) (*intransitive*; ～に努める): make an effort, endeavor. [Examples](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8A%AA%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B).

And there is also [勤める](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/147798/m0u/%E5%8B%A4%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B/).

Comment: Interestingly, 勤める can take both に and を. Not for the same function though. 看護師として病院に勤める。(I am unsure if として can be replaced by を here). Nevertheless, there is at least one case where を is ok according to [goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/147798/m0u/つとめる/) 法事を勤める。

Comment: In fact, I'm not really sure if "(病院で)看護師を勤める" is correct. As a "textbook" rule, I think it's at least unsafe, but [even 漱石, 芥川 and 太宰 used を勤める that way](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/examples/jn2/147798/m0u/%E3%81%A4%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B/)...